# Insertion sort for list of list

Tags: python, insertion-sort

i have a 2d list, contains some information like, and would like to have the list to be sorted based on price, `list[8]`

```
flights = [
['22-04-02', 'TR980', '06:00', '09:50', 'Singapore(SIN)', 'HongKong(HKG)', 'Yes', '/', '148', '0', '500', '156'], 
['22-04-03', 'TR980', '06:00', '09:50', 'Singapore(SIN)', 'HongKong(HKG)', 'Yes', '/', '148', '0', '500', '235'], 
['22-04-04', 'TR980', '06:00', '09:50', 'Singapore(SIN)', 'HongKong(HKG)', 'Yes', '/', '148', '0', '500', '342'], 
['22-04-05', 'TR980', '06:00', '09:50', 'Singapore(SIN)', 'HongKong(HKG)', 'Yes', '/', '148', '0', '500', '23'], 
['22-04-06', 'MF852', '15:25', '19:30', 'Singapore(SIN)', 'Xiamen(XMN)', 'Yes', '/', '16841', '2x32kg', '500', '238']
]
```

```
def insertionSort(flights, key = lambda x: x):
    for index in range(1, len(flights)):
        currentValue = flights[index]
        position = index 
        while position >0 and flights[position - 1] > currentValue: 
            flights[position] = flights [position -1]
            position -= 1
        flights[position] = currentValue
    return flights

sorted_list = insertionSort(flights, key = lambda x: int(x[8])) 
print(sorted_list)
```

but the sorted list only be able to be sorted by the date.

Comment: Why not use the built-in standard library sort?

Comment: Looks like homework. Insertion sort worst case in `O(n^2)`, no reason to use it except for small inputs.

Comment: Please format your question well

Comment: you get `key` but you never use it. You should compare `key(...) > key(...)` like `key(flights[position - 1]) > key(currentValue)`

Answer (score 0):

You get `key` but you never use it. You should compare `key(...) > key(...)`

```
key(flights[position - 1]) > key(currentValue)
```

---

The same you could get with standard `sorted()`

```
sorted_list = sorted(flights, key=lambda x: int(x[8]))
```